# mmenu.js - Use Dynamic DOM Elements for Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I really love the mmenu.js plugin.  It's so slick and has a wealth of extremely helpful features.

I'm having a small problem with the search function, though.  When I add any elements to the mmenu with javascript, they're unavailable for live-search.  Is there any way to refresh the mmenu or ensure the the search function is looking through the most recent version of the DOM and not just the elements that were present upon initialization?

Thanks

**Menu Markup**

```
<nav id="my-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="Label">Menu</li>
        <li><a href="/profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="/reports">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="/sign-out">Sign-Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**mmenu.js Startup**

```
$("#my-menu").mmenu({
    searchfield: {
        add: true,
        search: true
    }
});
```

**Add Item to Menu**

```
$("#my-menu ul").append('<li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>');
```

In this example, the newly added "Blog" link doesn't react as a part of the search function.

Comment: Can you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of this behavior?

Comment: @CDoe I have same issue, did you resolve?

Comment: No.  It doesn't seem like the plugin works that way.  I ended up writing a custom search function to hide and show items.  Later, I discovered that you can't really destroy mmenu and that didn't play nicely with my realtime JS framework, so in the end, I switched to Semantic-UI's sidebar. http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

Comment: How could you nest multiple submenu with semantic-ui sidebar ? no way from documentation